# jQuery .on() delegation with selector that matches nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, delegation, event-bubbling

```js
// Example A
$("#delegate").on("click", function(event) {
  // executes on click on any descendant of #delegate or self (not a delegate at all)
  // 'this' is #delegate
});


// Example B
$("#delegate").on("click", "#outer", function(event) {
  // executes on click on any descendant of #outer or self
  // 'this' is #outer or #inner (depends on the actual click)
});

$("#delegate").on("click", "#inner", function(event) {
  // executes on click on any descendant of #inner or self (nothing happens when clicking #outer)
  // 'this' is #inner
});


// Example C (now it's getting weird)
$("#delegate").on("click", "div", function(event) {
  // executes twice, when clicking #inner, because the event passes #outer when bubbling up

  // one time 'this' is #inner, and the other time 'this' is #outer
  // stopPropagation() // actually prevents the second execution
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="delegate">
  <div id="outer">
    outer
    <div id="inner">
      inner
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do you explain this behaviour logically?

There is exactly one click event, which starts on `#inner`, bubbles through `#outer` and finally reaches `#delegate`.

The event is catched (exactly) once by the `#delegate`'s on-handler. The handler checks if event's history contains any div elements.

If this applies, the callback function should be called once. That's what I would expect. "Single Event, single Handler, single Condition, single Callback".

It gets more crazy if you take a look at the `stopPropagation()` behaviour. You can actually avoid the second execution, though the event has already reached `#delegate`. `stopPropagation(`should not work here.

What kind of "magic" is done in the implementation of the on-delegation logic? Do event-bubbling and program flow split up in any way?

Please don't post "practical advice" in the first place ("Use xyz instead!"). I'd like to understand why the code works the ways it does.

Comment: You're missing the `click` event in the second and third call.

Comment: Are you only asking about the last case, with delegation to `div`?

Comment: Thank you. I've just added the click events to my post. And yes: Basically i'm just asking about the last case.

Comment: what is your question? "How do you explain this behaviour logically?" well, there are two `<div>`s in `#delegate`, and attaching a click event to all divs inside it will hence fire 2 events when clicking `#inner`.
Of course using stopPropagation will prevent bubbling from `#inner ` to `#outer`

Comment: So the event dosn't bubble up to #delegate and THEN executes the callback? Instad the handlers/callbacks are actually attached to the particular divs?

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/58kq61o9/2/

Comment: see here with only example C: http://jsfiddle.net/58kq61o9/4/

Answer (score 0):

As you have bound events on all the divs in two ways:

1. Using id attribute of the element div.
2. Using the tag name of the element div.

so if you `event.stopPropagation();` on the last one still the alert will come two times because you have cliked the div and also the `#inner` *(for instance.)*

Check the snippet below.

```js
$("#delegate").on("click", function(event) {
  alert(this.id);
});

/*
$("#delegate").on('click', "#outer", function(event) {
  alert(this.id);
});

$("#delegate").on('click', "#inner", function(event) {
  alert(this.id);
});

*/
// now it's getting weird
$("#delegate").on("click", "div", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="delegate">
  <div id="outer">
    outer
    <div id="inner">
      inner
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to tell that all the different .on()-calls in my snippet are different examples and aren't set at the same time. "now it's getting weird"-call is the only one you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

The way event delegation works is that jQuery walks up the DOM tree from the innermost target to the element that the delegation was bound to, testing each element to see if it matches the selector. If it does, it executes the handler with `this` bound to that element.

When `event.stopPropagation` is called, it sets a flag in the `event` object. The loop that walks the DOM tree also calls `event.isPropagationStopped()`. If propagation is stopped, it breaks out of the loop.

In other words, jQuery is doing its own bubbling and propagation stopping when it implements delegation, it's not making use of the browser's bubbling (except that this bubbling is necessary for the initial event to be triggered on `#delegate`, so that the jQuery loop will run).

Comment: Hm... seems the understanding of "jQuery does its own bubbling besides/before the browers bubbling" was the hint I was missing. Thank you. ;)

Comment: jQuery doesnt add its "own" bubbling. It adds bubbling for browsers not supporting it, like IE8 for the change event.

Comment: I guess I was misunderstanding that part of the code. But it still does its own check for `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58kq61o9/4/):

```
$("#delegate").on("click", "div", function(event) {
  // event.stopPropagation();
  alert('div: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Clicking `#inner` will fire the above event. The event will bubble up to `#outer` since `#inner` is a descendent of `#outer`. Since `#outer` also is a `<div`, the event will be fired on `#outer`, also. Logically, clicking on `#inner` will first alert "div: inner" and then "div: outer".

Calling `event.stopPropagation()` tells the event not to bubble up, so `#outer` stays uninvoked.

Other than in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58kq61o9/5/):

```
<div id="delegate">
  <div id="first">
    first
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    second
      <div id="third">
        third, inside second
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on third will first alert `third`, then `second` and then stop, because `#first` is not a parent but a sibling.